# Access rights on Laravel gates not detected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-gate

I want to create two access rights on the gate, namely `isAdmin` and `isCustomer`, but why is `isCustomer` not detected and is always directed to isAdmin. But whatever role I use to log in, it's always detected as admin.

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('isAdmin', function($user) {
        return $user->role == 'admin';
    });

    Gate::define('isCustomer', function($user) {
        return $user->role == 'customer';
    });
}
```

**Blade/View** using '@can' directive

```
@can('isAdmin')
<li class="sidebar-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link"
       href="{{ asset('lte/monster-html/table-basic.html') }}" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="me-3 fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Pesanan</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="sidebar-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link"
       href="{{ asset('lte/monster-html/icon-fontawesome.html') }}" 
           aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="me-3 fa fa-font" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Pembayaran</span>
    </a>
</li>
@elsecan('isCustomer')
<li class="sidebar-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link"
       href="{{ asset('lte/monster-html/table-basic.html') }}" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="me-3 fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu">Pesan Yok</span>
    </a>
</li>
@endcan
```

Comment: I think the `@can()` directive is for policy not the Gate. So you need to create a policy and pass the policy method to `@can()`. If you just want to use Gate. try this `@if (Gate::allows('isAdmin'))` in your view.